# Creating a list from a dictionary - python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I have the following xml file, which contains duplicate groupId's. I want to convert it into a dictionary which accepts this multiple ID's.

So far when I try to convert list to dictionary it eliminates all of the keys(but the last one).

So I want to convert my dictionary into a list.
Any help in achieving this?

The XML is :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5.ga</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Code

```
depend = root.xpath("//*[local-name()='dependency']")
dependencyInfo = defaultdict(dict)

    for dep in depend:
        infoList = []
        self.counter += 1
        for child in dep.getchildren():
            infoList.append(child.tag.split('}')[1])
            infoList.append(child.text)

           
        dependencyInfo[infoList[1]].update({infoList[2] : infoList[3],infoList[4] : infoList[5]})
```

Output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'junit': [{'artifactId': 'junit', 'version': '3.8.1'}], 'org.hibernate': [{'artifactId': 'hibernate-core', 'version': '3.6.3.Final'}})
```

Expected output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'junit': [{'artifactId': 'junit', 'version': '3.8.1'}], 'org.hibernate': [{'artifactId': 'hibernate-core', 'version': '3.6.3.Final'}, 'org.hibernate': [{'artifactId': 'hibernate', 'version': '3.2.5.ga'}, 'org.hibernate': [{'artifactId': 'hibernate-entitymanager', 'version': '3.3.2.GA'}})
```

From what Ive researched is that a Dictionary cant have duplicated values, so i need to put it in a list or set.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how the final dictionary `dependencyInfo` should look ?

Comment: updated @Daniser

Comment: The expected output contains the key `org.hibernate` multiple times (because `groupId` in the XML containes the same text multiple times). You should consider a different structure (hierarchy of lists and dicts) for the final output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another thought using [`xmltodict`](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/)

```
import xmltodict
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(list)

with open("pom_file_path>") as f:
    parse_ = xmltodict.parse(f.read()).get('project', {})

    for d in parse_.get("dependencies", {}).get("dependency", []):
        results[d['groupId']].append(
            {"artifactId": d['artifactId'], 'version': d['version']}
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really clear on what you are trying to do, but I think your issue is that you are defining your list (infoList) in every iteration.

Move `infoList = []` out of the loop to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the indentation is wrong, try this:

```
depend = root.xpath("//*[local-name()='dependency']")
dependencyInfo = defaultdict(dict)

for dep in depend:
    infoList = []
    self.counter += 1
    for child in dep.getchildren():
        infoList.append(child.tag.split('}')[1])
        infoList.append(child.text)

    # this is inside the for loop
    dependencyInfo[infoList[1]].update({infoList[2]: infoList[3], infoList[4]: infoList[5]})
```

You need `dependencyInfo` to change **inside** the "for" loop,

otherwise it will be updated with information from the **last iteration**.

Comment: Sorry, edited my code. When I put into stackoverflow it messed up the indents.